# The size of the cache line is level 2 - C ++

Tags: c++, caching, cpu, massive

I'm writing a program to determine the size of the second-level cache line, I used the article http://igoro.com/archive/gallery-of-processor-cache-effects/. But I have completely different results. Through the Coreinfo program, I learned that the size of the first and second level strings is 64 bytes in length. While I decided to get at least the size of the first level line, but some completely inadequate results are obtained

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <time.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


using namespace std;


int main()
{
    int t;
    const int N = 8000;
    volatile int arr[N];
    unsigned int A;
    char ask1 = 'y';

    srand(time(NULL));

    while (ask1 == 'y')
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
            arr[j] = rand();

        for (int i = 1; i <= 64; i++)
        {
            A = clock();
            for (int k = 0; k < 100000; k++)
                for (int j = 0; j < N; j += i)
                {
                    t = arr[j];
                }
            //cout << i << "\tstep, time\t" << clock() - A << '\t' << t << endl;
            arr[i] = (clock() - A); //Instead of printing, so as not to destroy the cache, I decided to write the execution time in the same array, and then output it
        }
        for (int i = 1; i <= 64; i++)
            cout << i << "\tstep, time\t" << arr[i] << endl;
        cout << "Repeat?(y/n): ";
        cin >> ask1;
        cout << endl;
    }
    /**/


    const int n = 1600000000;

    int l;

    unsigned int a;
    char ask = 'y';
    srand(time(NULL)); //it's just for random filling, so it's always been different, although here it's not really necessary for me
    while (ask == 'y')
    {
        volatile int byte8[2];

        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
            byte8[j] = rand(); 

        a = clock();//write the time before reading array cycles
        for (int k = 0; k < n / 2; k++) /*divide n by the number of 
repetitions of the inner cycle, so that everywhere in
the same number of repetitions */
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
                l = byte8[i];
        cout << size(byte8) * 4 << "\tbytes\t" << clock() - a << endl; 
//output the number of ms needed for reading
// we repeat the same for arrays of longer length


        volatile int byte16[4];
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            byte16[j] = rand();

        a = clock();
        for (int k = 0; k < n / 4; k++)
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                l = byte16[i];
        cout << size(byte16) * 4 << "\tbytes\t" << clock() - a << endl;

        volatile int byte32[8];
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
            byte32[j] = rand();

        a = clock();
        for (int k = 0; k < n / 8; k++)
            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
                l = byte32[i];
        cout << size(byte32) * 4 << "\tbytes\t" << clock() - a << endl;
        /*
        int byte60[15];
        for (int j = 0; j < 15; j++)
        byte60[j] = rand();

        a = clock();
        for (int k = 0; k < n / 15; k++)
        for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
        l = byte60[i];
        cout << size(byte60) * 4 << "\tbytes\t" << clock() - a << endl;
        */
        volatile int byte64[16];
        for (int j = 0; j < 16; j++)
            byte64[j] = rand();

        a = clock();
        for (int k = 0; k < n / 16; k++)
            for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
                l = byte64[i];
        cout << size(byte64) * 4 << "\tbytes\t" << clock() - a << endl;
        /*
        int byte68[17];
        for (int j = 0; j < 17; j++)
        byte68[j] = rand();

        a = clock();
        for (int k = 0; k < n / 17; k++)
        for (int i = 0; i < 17; i++)
        l = byte68[i];
        cout << size(byte68) * 4 << "\tbytes\t" << clock() - a << endl;
        */
        volatile int byte96[24];
        for (int j = 0; j < 24; j++)
            byte96[j] = rand();

        a = clock();
        for (int k = 0; k < n / 24; k++)
            for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++)
                l = byte96[i];
        cout << size(byte96) * 4 << "\tbytes\t" << clock() - a << endl;

        volatile int byte128[32];
        for (int j = 0; j < 32; j++)
            byte128[j] = rand();

        a = clock();
        for (int k = 0; k < n / 32; k++)
            for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
                l = byte128[i];
        cout << size(byte128) * 4 << "\tbytes\t" << clock() - a << endl;

        volatile int byte192[48];
        for (int j = 0; j < 48; j++)
            byte192[j] = rand();

        a = clock();
        for (int k = 0; k < n / 48; k++)
            for (int i = 0; i < 48; i++)
                l = byte192[i];
        cout << size(byte192) * 4 << "\tbytes\t" << clock() - a << endl;

        volatile int byte256[64];
        for (int j = 0; j < 64; j++)
            byte256[j] = rand();

        a = clock();
        for (int k = 0; k < n / 64; k++)
            for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++)
                l = byte256[i];
        cout << size(byte256) * 4 << "\tbytes\t" << clock() - a << endl;

        volatile int byte512[128];
        for (int j = 0; j < 128; j++)
            byte512[j] = rand();

        a = clock();
        for (int k = 0; k < n / 128; k++)
            for (int i = 0; i < 128; i++)
                l = byte512[i];
        cout << size(byte512) * 4 << "\tbytes\t" << clock() - a << endl;


        cout << "Repeat?(y/n): ";
        cin >> ask;
        cout << endl;
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

- 1    step, time      369
- 2    step, time      184
- 3    step, time      123
- 4    step, time      101
- 5    step, time      77
- 6    step, time      60
- 7    step, time      52
- 8    step, time      45
- 9    step, time      44
- 10   step, time      38
- 11   step, time      33
- 12   step, time      32
- 13   step, time      29
- 14   step, time      26
- 15   step, time      31
- 16   step, time      26
- 17   step, time      22
- 18   step, time      21
- 19   step, time      20
- 20   step, time      18
- 21   step, time      18
- 22   step, time      18
- 23   step, time      16
- 24   step, time      16
- 25   step, time      15
- 26   step, time      16
- 27   step, time      15
- 28   step, time      21
- 29   step, time      14
- 30   step, time      13
- 31   step, time      12
- 32   step, time      12
- 33   step, time      12
- 34   step, time      13
- 35   step, time      11
- 36   step, time      12
- 37   step, time      11
- 38   step, time      10
- 39   step, time      11
- 40   step, time      18
- 41   step, time      10
- 42   step, time      10
- 43   step, time      10
- 44   step, time      26
- 45   step, time      9
- 46   step, time      9
- 47   step, time      9
- 48   step, time      8
- 49   step, time      9
- 50   step, time      8
- 51   step, time      9
- 52   step, time      8
- 53   step, time      8
- 54   step, time      8
- 55   step, time      8
- 56   step, time      7
- 57   step, time      7
- 58   step, time      8
- 59   step, time      7
- 60   step, time      7
- 61   step, time      7
- 62   step, time      7
- 63   step, time      6
- 64   step, time      7
- Repeat?(y/n): n
- 8    bytes   1227
- 16   bytes   1736
- 32   bytes   951
- 64   bytes   862
- 96   bytes   805
- 128  bytes   805
- 192  bytes   769
- 256  bytes   1232
- 512  bytes   909
- Repeat?(y/n): y
- 8    bytes   1220
- 16   bytes   1739
- 32   bytes   944
- 64   bytes   842
- 96   bytes   815
- 128  bytes   804
- 192  bytes   781
- 256  bytes   1220
- 512  bytes   905
- Repeat?(y/n):

The point is that I can not use functions like GetLogicalProcessorInformation, I need to define a test. I launch in Visual Studio 2017 with a configuration on Release. Sorry for my English

Comment: That's a lot of code.  What is it doing?

Comment: measures the time taken to read arrays from the cache so that based on these measurements, find the size of the cache line

Comment: I haven't the read the code but it appears that you initialize the array, this will offset the results since the CPU has already cached and loaded the pages. A better test may be to allocate a dynamic area of memory (to rule out TLB effects, you can keep it 4KiB in size or pin it) and read from it with different strides. Without a prefetcher (you most likely have one) you should see the mean time required to read an item increase linearly with the stride. With a prefetcher, there should be a clear jump once the stride is equal the cache line size (since prefetching is useless at that point).

Comment: Thank you)
But the topic can be closed. I was helped to understand this task in the Russian forum. (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/762689/Размер-кэша-строки-2-го-уровня-c?noredirect=1#comment1184105_762689)